# Program fails to execute statement

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

I know C programming very well, but I don't have much experience with Unix system calls. I am re-exploring my Unix knowledge after a long time. So I started with fork and execlp system calls. I am practicing examples on ubuntu_linux.

Here is a text book example program which accepts a command from STD_IN and executes it in a child process.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
   char command[MAX_LINE];
   pid_t pid;
   int   status;

   printf ("%% ");
   while (fgets (command,MAX_LINE,stdin ) != NULL){
        if (command[strlen(command)-1] == '\n')
          command[strlen(command)-1] = '\0';

        if ((pid=fork ()) < 0) {
           perror ("fork failed :  \n");
        }

        if (pid == 0) {
           printf (" I am child and my PID is %d",getpid ());
           execlp (command, command, (char *)0);
           perror ("couldn't execute:"); 
           exit(127);
        }

        printf (" I am parent and my PID is %d\n ",getpid ());
        if ((pid = waitpid (pid, &status, 0)) < 0){
            perror("waitpid error\n");
        }

        printf ("%% ");
    }
    exit (0);
}
```

I put some `printf` statments but the program didn't print the line **" I am child and my PID is"** whenever the command is executed successfully. However, it prints the above line if the input command is incorrect and it fails.

I am expecting the line to be printed in both scenario as the print statement is before `execlp`.

Comment: You might want to flush your printf before execlp, ie fflush(stdout) and see what you get.

Comment: why you are always printing error and forcing your child to exit with fail?

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue: i know fflush will solve it issue. but program is displaying output of perror which is after printf. here, stdout and stderr both are pointing to console only.

Comment: @Sachin, stderr is autoflushed.  But stdout is not autoflushed and is being flushed when you call exit.

Comment: If you don't print a newline, your output is not flushed.  Especially when debugging, 'always' print a newline at the end of any diagnostic output.  Optionally, use `fflush()` too for added guarantees.

Comment: Please put the parentheses for a function call touching the function name, and please leave a space after the commas in argument lists.  Be meticulous and self-consistent.

Answer (score 0):

This should flush the stdout before the exec.

```
printf (" I am child and my PID is %d",getpid ());
fflush(stdout);
execlp (command, command, (char *)0);
```